# How to prevent ADODB.Connection pooling?

Tags: powershell-2.0, adodb

I'm using Powershell v2.0, question is in the title.  I'm having to use the old school ADOB.Connection (*not* the OLEDB provider) to open a Jet DB file (.mdb).  The reason is simple, the ADODB.Connection exposes properties I need access to that the OLEDB provider doesn't.

I'm opening the DB via ADOB.Connection to query for some information, and then I'm trying to compact the DB using JRO.JetEngine.  The issue is that I keep getting an error about the Jet DB being locked.

I'm explicitly calling Close on it, and setting the variable to $null, and still experiencing that issue.  My best guess is that ADODB.Connection is using connection pooling, and so is not releasing the resources the way it should be.

According to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/191572, the call to close() should be enough, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Is there a way for me to explicitly specify no connection pooling when creating ADODB.Connection objects?

Comment: Varying the connection string by an unimportant parameter (say time out seconds) might prevent pooling, since pooling sometimes only works for identical connection strings. I'm sure there is some provider specific behavior, so JET could be different.

Answer (score 0):

In the link you provided, it is said that calling to close returns the connection to the pool:

> 2.What statement returns the connection to the pool?
>   2.Conn.Close

You might need to destroy/dispose the ADODB.Connection object, so that it is removed from the pool, or, if you are using OLE DB as the provider, configure the OLEDB Services, as explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810829.aspx):

> Enabling OLE DB Resource. 
>   Pooling Resource pooling can be enabled in
>   several ways:
>
> For an ADO-based consumer, by keeping one open instance of a
>   Connection object for each unique user and using the OLEDB_SERVICES
>   connection string attribute to enable or disable pooling. By default,
>   ADO attempts to use pooling, but if you do not keep at least one
>   instance of a Connection object open for each user, there will not be
>   a persistent pool available to your application. (However, Microsoft
>   Transaction Server keeps pools persistent as long as the connections
>   in them have not been released and have not eventually timed out.)